# how to select Options as Editable or Make the select box as input?

Tags: angularjs

This Is my select tag. i want to make this As editable.
if possible change this as Input text.
here my ng-model is object showing as list.productcode.

```
<select class="default form-control" ng-options="list.productcode for list in getproductList" ng-model="list"></select>
```

please help how to change this.

Comment: you can use autocomplete select option.

Comment: please provide any demo if possible.

Comment: may be help you https://github.com/axel-zarate/js-custom-select

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
        datalist
```

is the  html5 tag

```
       <input type="search"    ng-model="txtModel" list="list" />

       <datalist id="list" ng-model="list">

       <option   data-ng-repeat="data in list" value="{{data.ColumnName}}">
      </option>
      </datalist>
```

Note ColumnName is the Name of Column you can use

Comment: why you are using two ng-models?

Comment: one for data-list one for textbox

Comment: actually it is necassary to give model to datalist in order to relate it with textbox

Comment: i am not searching for any thing. i am sending the object using the select options. but it is not possible with textbox. ng-model as the list.productcode. check the above my question. Thanking you for quick response.

Comment: In this your textbox will behave like select i ve used this approach in my project